# Activate (or not) jQuery plugin depending on screen width

Tags: jquery-plugins

So I got this jQuery plugin to active a sliding menu tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var closeAll,
    $parentItem = $('div#tabWrapper'),
    slideAmt = $('div#tabBG').width(),
    direction;

$('a#toggle').click(function() {
        if (parseInt($parentItem.css('marginLeft'), 10) < 0) {
            direction = '+=';
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
            direction = '-=';
        }
    $parentItem.animate({marginLeft: direction + slideAmt}, 400)
    return false;
});

$parentItem.mouseleave(function() {
    closeAll = setTimeout(function() {
        $('a#toggle').removeClass('expanded').parent().animate({marginLeft: -slideAmt}, 300);
        return false;
    }, 600);
})
.mouseenter(function() {
clearTimeout(closeAll);
})  });
```

But I only want this animation to work on a higher screen width than 1024px.

How would make this happen?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen resolution using

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

Then do what you want to do depending on these values

Comment: Sorry I'm realy a noob in jQuery. I tried adding `if (screen.width>=1024)` at the beginning of the code, without success...

Comment: `if (screen.width >= 1024) { // code to run };` should work. Very simple example : http://jsfiddle.net/k55fU/